# Text being chopped off after special characters when doing a replaceWith in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm entering text into a textarea, which would be a note coming from a user. The string looks like this. If it has special characters in it, some of the text gets chopped with the replace call in javascript.

Here is the text.

```
This "email" and any files transmitted with it are proprietary and ?><??><intended solely for the use of the individual or entity to whom they are addressed. If you have received this email in error please notify the system manager. Please note that any views or opinions presented in this email :"":&((*)((*)(*)( are solely those of the author and do not necessarily represent those of the company.
```

Here is what I do in Javascript. 'newNote' is my textarea

```js
$(newNote).replaceWith("<div name=\"note\" class=\"contractNote\">" + "<span style=\"white-space: pre-line\">" + $(newNote).val() + "</span></div>");
```

Here is what I see on the page after. It looks like everything after a special character gets chopped off.

> This "email" and any files transmitted with it are proprietary and ?>

Comment: Please produce a proper snippet and show where the newNote comes from.

Comment: hi. I tried setting up a fiddle but it's not working correctly https://jsfiddle.net/2ornkk2u/

Comment: You have nested double quotes in the text. Escape them

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2ornkk2u/1/

Comment: <??> and <intended are seen as tags and invisible - https://jsfiddle.net/nnmfe7L2/

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/nnmfe7L2/1/

`<??>` and `<intended ....` are seen as tags and are not rendered

This is a pure HTML issue

Do a string replace of all `<` to `&lt;` before inserting the string into the DOM

```
$('#note').replaceWith("<div name=\"note\" class=\"contractNote\"><span style=\"white-space: pre-line\">" +
text.replace(/</g,"&lt;") + 
"</span></div>");
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can reproduce this issue with a fiddle then, I just know I'm having this problem in the jquery and don't want to see chopped off text. So, I'm still not sure how to handle it? Do I need to look for certain characters and do something with them???

Comment: You do not have chopped off text. You need to change all < to `&lt;`

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this too.**

```
var textarea = $('textarea');

var text = textarea.val().replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");

textarea.replaceWith("<div name='note' class='contractNote'><span style='white-space: pre-line'>" + text  + "</span></div>");
```

Comment: Only the < needs replacing as I suggested